# Usage of jsTree functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jstree

I'm looking at the [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/themes) plugin API, and can't understand where the API functions (`set_theme`, `show_dots` etc.) are to be used.

I see in [this](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core#api) page some functions preceded by `jQuery`, whilst some are preceeded by a dot, how do these two types of functions defer? How do I use the latter?

Comment: I tried using `set_theme` as a function of `jstree`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways to call a function on the tree instance of the jsTree plugin:

```
/* METHOD ONE */
jQuery("some-selector-to-container-node-here")
    .jstree("operation_name" [, argument_1, argument_2, ...]);

/* METHOD TWO */
jQuery.jstree._reference(needle) 
    /* NEEDLE can be a DOM node or selector for the container or a node within the container */
    .operation_name([ argument_1, argument_2, ...]);
```

refer to this documentation page for more info: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

so when you see this: `.set_theme ( name , url )` in the docs
it means that you can use it like that:

```
/* METHOD ONE */
$('#treeContainer').jstree("set_theme ","ThemeName","\PathToTheme\Here");

/* METHOD TWO */
var $MYjsTreeObj = $('#treeContainer').jstree({...});
jQuery.jstree._reference($MYjsTreeObj).set_theme ("ThemeName","\PathToTheme\Here");
```